Syncing product images from Shopify to Sanity in a headless Next.js storefront
I'm building a headless storefront with Next.js for my Shopify store, using Sanity as the primary content management system. I've set up the Sanity Connect app in Shopify, and it successfully syncs products and collections with my Sanity dataset. However, I noticed that product images are not being synced by default.
My app currently uses the Shopify Storefront API for core e-commerce functions (cart, checkout, etc.). I’d like to know if there's a way to sync product images to my Sanity dataset alongside other product data. Or, do I need to fetch product images directly from the Shopify Storefront API in my Next.js application?
Any guidance on how to handle image syncing in this setup would be greatly appreciated!
